# A better way to send the arguments as an object literal?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, arguments, object-literal

I have this function code that I am using to create a code snippet in javascript. I want to know if I can make it look better since I think this code I did is not looking professionally well.

I would like to know if there is any better way of passing multiple parameters to a function in javascript sending the arguments as an object literal?

Many thanks.

```js
let headings = document.getElementById('headlines');

function create(listLi, txt, p) {
  let li = document.createElement(listLi)
  li.innerHTML = txt;
  p.appendChild(li);
  return li;
}

let ul = create('ul', null, document.body);
```

Comment: A fixed number of three arguments is going to be more efficient to pass as three separate arguments like you are already doing.  Passing as an object is appropriate for many more arguments/options or a number of optional arguments/options.

Answer (score 2):

You can use destructuring.

```js
function create({listLi, txt, p}) {
  let li = document.createElement(listLi)
  li.innerHTML = txt;
  p.appendChild(li);
  return li;
}

let ul = create({
  listLi: 'ul',
  txt: null,
  p: document.body
});
```

Comment: when I replace with this destructuring I get an error -- lmanha_jv_t1.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Comment: I would like to share the full code with you.  link - https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/yqoxcLfb/32/

Comment: Don't worry my friend. I actually fixed the issue making the create function a constant variable for the function. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @barmar this an elegant solution - many thanks for sharing it.